# ASP.NET MVC: Where do you assemble the view model for a view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, repository-pattern

From inside to outside, these are our MVC app layers:

1. MS SQL / Tables / Views / Stored Procs
2. Entity Framework 4.1 (ORM) with POCO generation
3. Repository
4. Service (retrieve) and Control Functions (Save)
5. Routing -> Controller -> Razor View
6. (client) JQuery Ajax with Knockout.js (MVVM)

Everything is fine until I need to create a single ViewModel for step 5 to feed both the Razor view as well as the JSON/Knockout ViewModel:

- Header that includes all Drop down list options and choices for the fields below
- Items - an array of whatever we send to the client that becomes the ViewModel

Since the Controller won't have access to the Repository directly, **does this mean I create a service for each and every view that allows editing content?**  I'll need to get the POCO from the repository plus all options for each field type as needed.

It just seems redundant to create separate services for each view.  For example, a viewModel to edit an address and a separate viewModel to edit a real estate property that also has an address.  We could have a dozen forms that edit the same address POCO.

To make this question easier to answer, is allowing the Controller direct access to the repositories a leaky abstraction?

Comment: are you enjoying knockout?  i've always wanted to find a reason to use it, and never have.

Comment: @nathan You should checkout this video http://channel9.msdn.com/events/mix/mix11/frm08.  It will help to find reasons to use it.  It reduces code to about half.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, so are your controllers going to have code that translates POCOs from Entity Framework into separate view model objects?

If so, then you should move that code to a separate class, and follow the single-responsibility principle. Whether that class is in the "service layer" or not is up to you. And whether you use AutoMapper or not is up to you. But these kind of [data mappers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) should not be part of the controller logic; controllers should be as dumb as possible.

---

OK, now let's ignore the data mapping problem, and pretend you could always use your POCOs directly as view models. Then you would *still* want a service layer, because it would translate between

```
userService.GetByUserName("bob")
```

in your dumb controller, and implement that in a specific manner by returning

```
userRepository.Users.Single(u => u.UserName == "bob")
```

---

Putting these together, your `UserController` ends up taking in `IUserService` and `IUserDataMapper` dependencies, and the code is super-dumb, as desired:

```
public ActionResult ShowUserPage(string userName)
{
    var user = userService.GetByUserName(userName);
    var viewModel = userDataMapper.MakeViewModel(user);

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

You can now test the controller with stubs for both dependencies, or stub out `IUserDataMapper` while you mock `IUserService`, or vice-versa. Your controller has very little logic, and [has only one axis of change](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html). The same can be said for the user data-mapper class and the user service class.

---

I was reading an article this morning that you might find somewhat illuminating on these architectural matters. It is, somewhat condescendingly, titled "[Software Development Fundamentals, Part 2: Layered Architecture](http://hendryluk.wordpress.com/2009/08/17/software-development-fundamentals-part-2-layered-architecture/)." You probably won't be able to switch from a database application model to the persistent-ignorant model the article describes and suggests. But it might point you in the right direction.

Comment: That's the part I was missing, to separate the Service that gets Entities from the mechanic that creates a viewModel from a collection of entities.  I assume the `userDataMapper.MakeViewModel` would be able to query the database for the possible options for a drop down list for example to place in the header of the viewModel?

Comment: Well, it depends---do you want to be able to unit test your data mapper without a live database? If so, then the data mapper should probably be injected with with some kind of `IOptionsConfiguration` or `IOptionsRepository`. Then the related code in the data-mapper becomes just `options.GetUserTypes()` or whatever, and your tests can stub that interface as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

i personally always inject the repository/repositories into the controller.  i'm not sure why you would want to have a service layer between the repository and the controller.  if anything you would use specifications.

once you've done that, check out [automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).  its a mapper that, once properly configured, can map your domain model to your viewmodel, and back again.

Comment: Careful, your mention of specifications makes me think you are talking about _Domain Driven Design_ repositories, whereas the OP's question seems to indicate he is working primarily with an anemic DTO layer and the _Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture_ concept of repository.